# Migrating FORTRAN95 and VC++6 code causes NaNs

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, fortran, migration, fortran95

I am working on a project that was written in FORTRAN95 (using the FTN95 compiler) and VC++6 that was moved to Intel Parallel Studio 15 and Visual Studio 2012 respectively. Since the migration, other features were added, but it was now discovered that an older feature generates NaN values at run-time in the FORTRAN code.

After several hours of debugging the program I am quite sure that the new features are not to blame, mainly because I only found causes of the bug in code which is the same as in the latest working version of the program (compiled with FTN95 & VC++6). Therefore I tend to believe that the issue was caused by the migration itself. Now the problem is that the program compiles without errors. Therefore I'm asking for any ideas on how I could solve this issue.

I know the description is vague at best and I cannot give many details about the bug since it stretches thousands of lines of code (the application is used for scientific calculations). Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Some general details about the bug

The program gets user input from the GUI and initializes corresponding variables in FORTRAN. This stage works as expected and values are passed correctly. After all the desired options have been chosen, the FORTRAN code runs it's calculations and outputs it's results (the NaN values) to a file.

Comment: Enable FP NaN exceptions on the Fortran side and catch the first NaN being generated, then figure out why. Or, disable FP NaN exceptions in C++ and cross fingers... Sorry, but you can't seriously expect any substantive help with `I know the description is vague at best and I cannot give many details about the bug since it stretches thousands of lines of code`.

Comment: @dxiv I tried enabling FP exceptions in FORTRAN but no exceptions were ever raised, any ideas as to why that might happen?

Comment: Then either FP exceptions get re-disabled somewhere, or there is a top level exception handler that masks them. Can't really guess without any context whatsoever. One other thing to note is that many scientific calculations do purposely use `NaN`s (to flag errors or special cases, for example), so that alone does not necessarily indicate a malfunction.

Comment: You write that you *found causes of the bug in code* but you don't share with us what you found, what causes you deduced, what operations were being performed when the NaNs popped up, what lines of code led to NaNs.  You're not providing much help ...

Comment: @High Performance Mark You're right I didn't express myself clearly enough. I meant that I found the parts of code responsible for the NaN values, but couldn't understand why that happened since that code worked perfectly well in older version. Eventually I narrowed the problem down to lost data from `COMMON BLOCK`s. I posted a question and later an answer related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142569/fortran-block-data-seems-to-not-be-working?noredirect=1#comment63715091_38142569)