# FORTRAN block data seems to not be working

Tags: fortran, fortran77, intel-fortran, fortran95

I am working on some legacy code that relies heavily on common blocks which are initialized with `BLOCK DATA` similar to the code below.

```
       BLOCK DATA filename
       PARAMETER (size=100)
       CHARACTER*8 somearray(size)
       COMMON /block1/ somearray

       DATA(somearray(i), i=100)/ 
      *'string1', 'string2', ... , 'string100'/

       END
```

At some point in the program a subroutine uses this common block as shown in the code below.

```
       SUBROUTINE SUB(array)

       IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
       CHARACTER*8 array(*), somearray(100)

       COMMON /block1/ somearray

       DO 100 I=1, iterations
       array(I)=somearray(I)
       ...
  100  CONTINUE
       END
```

Here `somearray` has a couple of spaces in each string instead of the actual values specified in the `BLOCK DATA`. What could be the cause of this?

**Note**: the code is compiled with Intel Fortran

Comment: Can you create a full example (as a [mcve]) for us to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue by adding a `SAVE` statement before the `END` statement of any `BLOCK DATA` as seen below.

```
   BLOCK DATA filename
   PARAMETER (size=100)
   CHARACTER*8 somearray(size)
   COMMON /block1/ somearray

   DATA(somearray(i), i=100)/ 
  *'string1', 'string2', ... , 'string100'/
   SAVE
   END
```

Comment: you should improve this answer by showing an example. `common` blocks don't have "end statements" so it will likely be unclear to others what you mean.

Comment: To second, it would be good to show your complete modifications.  However, I'll also note that if you use `save` within the block data this works by given the common block the save attribute.  If you do this you should explicitly specify this attribute to the common block in every scope it occurs.  Finally, if this works it is because of the common block becoming inactive: had a complete example been given in the question we could have solved this 15 months ago.

Comment: @francescalus: I understand, however a complete example wasn't possible given the size and tight coupling of the program. Not knowing FORTRAN didn't help either.  

@agentp: If you look at the first code sample I provided, I added a `save`  statement before the `end`. Is it the `block data` that the `save` refers to then?

Comment: a  `block data` program unit and a common block are different things. That's why your answer is unclear, and showing the actual example would help.  In any case this issue arises because many compilers automatically saved everything in common blocks, to the point that lots of coders never bothered with explicit `save` statements.

Comment: @agentp: Thanks for clarifying and adding the bit about compilers. I edited the answer, let me know if it is clearer now.